# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, routes

I want to use routing and AngularJS in Ionic V1.
when I compile my program it prints out this error message:

```js
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionic due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngSanitize due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $filterProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$injector/unpr?p0=%24filterProvider
minErr/<@http://localhost:8100/js/angular/angular.js:78:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@http://localhost:8100/js/angular/angular.js:3544:19
getService@http://localhost:8100/js/angular/angular.js:3671:39
loadModules/<@http://localhost:8100/js/angular/angular.js:3625:45
forEach@http://localhost:8100/js/angular/angular.js:303:11
loadModules@http://localhost:8100/js/angular/angular.js:3614:12
loadModules/<@http://localhost:8100/js/angular/angular.js:3621:40
forEach@http://localhost:8100/js/angular/angular.js:303:11
loadModules@http://localhost:8100/js/angular/angular.js:3614:12
loadModules/<@http://localhost:8100/js/angular/angular.js:3621:40
```

as well as:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function
```

The project can be found under: codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-pine-px3iq

my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app_module.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/SensorCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/StartCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/service/state_route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/service/draw.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

my app module:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
```

my roting config:

```js
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'template_startseite.html'
    })
    .state('sensoren',{
      url:'/sensoren',
      templateUrl: 'template_sensorwerte.html'
    });
});
```

when I try the routing, then it only shows http://localhost:8100/ but not http://localhost:8100/index.html
so maybe this is why the routing doesn't work. But the error message shows that ionic isn't instantiated, do you have any ideas what I can do?

edit:
here is a picture of what the app shows on screen
[image: error]

edit2:
tmhao2005 pointed out that `<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>` was missing, it now works perfectly.

Comment: Can you copy your files to codesandbox which is easy to debug?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I would love to, but it doesn't support AngularJS, only Angular (which uses .ts files, not .js files. Is there any other way I can make it easiert to debug?

Comment: it could, mate. You could select templates > explore templates > search "angularjs"

Comment: @tmhao2005: That is awesome, thanks a lot, seems like I was too hasty there. The Link is: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-pine-px3iq

Comment: It’s working fine, isn’t it?

Comment: it isn't for me, the template and the controler are not loaded when the page is started. The <ion-nav-view> doesn't show the template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225173/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-tobias-d).

Answer (score 0):

For all who might encounter the same problem:

The problem seems to have been the 'ionic' in my app modue `var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic']);`

So I switched from the `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` to `<div ng-view></div>`
And from `$stateProvider.state` to `$routeProvider.when`

now it seems to work again, the routing function works too.
Would be nice to know why the 'ionic' didn't work though.